# Operators behaving strangely in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, operators, divide

My React app is confusing a "/" string with "+".

```
  console.log(numbers, signs);
```

This logs:

> Array [ "6", "2" ]   Array [ "/" ]

After this I iterate over the arrays and apply the appropriate operator, as shown below:

```
  for (let e = 1; e < numbers.length; e++) {
    if ((signs[counter] = "+")) {
      newTotal += parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] = "-")) {
      newTotal -= parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] = "*")) {
      newTotal *= parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] = "/")) {
      newTotal = newTotal / parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    }
```

Every operator works fine, except for "/", which always acts like "+". So the above code returns 8 instead of 3. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning signs[counter] to + on top of your if statement.
use ===

Answer (score 0):

In order to work properly your code should be like below:

```
let counter = 0;
for (let e = 1; e < numbers.length; e++) {
    if ((signs[counter] == "+")) {
      newTotal += parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] == "-")) {
      newTotal -= parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] == "*")) {
      newTotal *= parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    } else if ((signs[counter] == "/")) {
      newTotal = newTotal / parseInt(numbers[e]);
      counter += 1;
      console.log(newTotal);
    }
}
```